# How to overlap one div over another div without position

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, z-index

In the following code, I want to div1 to overlap div2 when div1 is clicked. 
How do i do that without using position?
And also I want to accomplish this by changing only the css of div1.
Thanks in advance.

```
<style>
.div1
{ display:'inline-block';}
.div2
{display:'inline-block';}
enter code here
</style>
<script>
function thefunc()
{
//code to overlap div2 from div1 by only changing css of div1
}

<body>
<div id='div1' onClick={()=>thefunc()}></div>
<div id='div2'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You cannot really not use position. I presume you mean pixel position e.g. `15px 2em`. But you can use things such as `absolute` or `relative`. So do you mean without pixel measurements, or without positioning at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider CSS-Grid applied to the `body`

```js
function thefunc() {
  document.querySelector('body').classList.add('overlap');
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  opacity: .5;
}

#div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
}

div[id] {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.overlap {
  display: grid
}

.overlap div {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

#div1 {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id='div1' onClick="thefunc()"></div>
<div id='div2'></div>
```